# Rails - wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I am having trouble with some code inside an application I am working on.
With the following code:

```
@herbivores=Deer.find(:all,:conditions =>['state like?', '%' + params[:number]+'%'])
@herbi=@herbivores.find(:all,:conditions =>['city like?', '%bad%'])
```

I receive the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

Can anybody explain what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the query API to keep the correct scope, and also do this more cleanly since `where` is chainable:

```
@herbivores=Deer.where('state like ?', '%' + params[:number]+'%')
@herbi=@herbivores.where('city like ?', '%bad%')
```

You can also chain these directly without an intermediate variable:

```
@herbi = Deer.where('state like ?', "%#{params[:number]}%").where('city like ?', "%bad%")
```

Or you can merge it into one method call:

```
@herbi = Deer.where('state like ? AND city like ?', "%#{params[:number]}%", "%bad%")
```

Comment: You could also chain these calls together: `@herbivores = Deer.where('state like ?', '%' + params[:number] + '%').where('city like ?', '%bad%')`

Comment: @DanielVandersluis: you could, but that would result in a different result than the OP seemed to want.  I'll add that as an additional point though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that you are treating `@herbivores` like its a model that you can find on, but it is an Array of Deer records so is not a model.

EDIT:
Purhaps you want:

```
@herbivores=Deer.find(:all,:conditions =>['state like ?', "%#{params[:number]}%"])
@herbivores.each do |herbi|
  if herbi.city == 'bad'
    puts "bad city in state #{ani.state}"
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach works, but will call the database many more times than necessary.  It's also quite verbose...

Comment: @PinnyM  I prefer your method but just for my own knowledge am I not right in saying it will only call the database once but will have a larger result set than yours as it is a less defined query (and be a heavier query)?

Comment: You are right, this would only hit the database more if 'city' were an association (which is apparently not the case here).  But it would have a larger result set, as you said.